# Ad pops up on lock screen after charging

Tags: google-play-store, malware, google-pixel

I know that others have complained about the same thing, but I have looked all over for this particular app and I cannot find which one may have caused the issue.

#### Issue:

When I turn on my phone, I am greeted by some sort of weather app that has an ad and some writing in a language I do not know.

#### More info:

- I have not downloaded any apps in the last week
- I have a google pixel (not rooted)
- It starts every time I plug my phone in
- This continues to happen about half an hour after the phone has been unplugged

#### Image of lock screen:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the lock screen App itself is providing Ads. Check for ES File explorer settings it may provide ads sometimes.